# Find minimum non-zero value in a column R

Tags: r, min

I have this situation in R:

```
my_minimum <- min(my_data_frame[,my_column_number])
```

This returns the minimum value. What I want is the minimum non-zero value.
I have seen a lot of more complicated situations where people want a vector of the non-zero minimum values but I simply want a single number, the lowest non-zero value that exists in

```
my_column_number
```

within

```
my_data_frame
```

For context, this is taking place within a for loop that iteratively plots some stuff for each column, and I need to get the non-zero minimum to add to the plot.

Comment: I take it we are to assume that there are no negative values?

Comment: You could also do `sort`.  `vals <- sort(my_data_frame[, my_column_number]); vals[!!vals][1]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That should do the trick.

```
 min(my_data_frame[my_data_frame$my_column_number>0,my_column_number])
```

Comment: Thanks heaps, as always the solution is obvious to the pros, still getting my head around setting limits in R

Answer (score 22):

If you use a vector:

```
min(myvector[myvector > 0])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
min(my_data_frame[,1][which(my_data_frame[,1]>0)])
```