# R: Mutate non zero minimum in grouped column

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, min

I am trying to calculate the non zero minimum of a column within groups using `dplyr`. I have seen a few similar questions around, however, none seem to work. Let's see an example with `iris`. I would like to create a new column :min_length, with the minimum pedal length higher than 1 for each species (I did not use 0 for this example to fit the dataset). I tried:

```
iris <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% mutate(min_length = min(Petal.Length>1))
```

But I get:

```
> iris$min_length
  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [58] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
[115] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Also, I tried an answer suggested in [Find minimum non-zero value in a column R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25615439/find-minimum-non-zero-value-in-a-column-r) :

```
iris$min_length <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% min(iris[iris$Sepal.Length>1, "Sepal.Length"])
```

But I get:

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :    only defined on a data frame with all
> numeric variables

The intended output would be:

```
iris$min_length
  [1] 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1
 [29] 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0
 [57] 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0
 [85] 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5
[113] 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5
[141] 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it

```
library(tidyverse)

iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% mutate(min_length = min(Petal.Length[Petal.Length > 1]))
```